# saving/loading linked lists in c

Tags: c, list, linked-list, save, gif

im making gif maker using opencv and linked lists

now the structure is

```
// Frame struct
typedef struct Frame
{
    char* name;
    unsigned int    duration;
    char* path;
} Frame;


// Link (node) struct
typedef struct FrameNode
{
    Frame* frame;
    struct FrameNode* next;
} FrameNode;
```

the frameNode contains a frame that has all the data and it has next that is used for the linked list

now i want to save the data after making a gif let's say i have 3 frameNodes in the list

```
Name            Duration                Path
1               200 ms            C:\Users\magshimim\Desktop\test\tt.png
2               500 ms
C:\Users\magshimim\Desktop\test\t.jpg
3               800 ms                  C:\Users\magshimim\Desktop\test\kitten_run.jpg
```

how do i save the name, duration, path and the next of each frameNode that when i comeback later on i can load the file and continue from where i left?

Comment: 1. Define the file format to use. 2. Implement load and save function for the file format.

Comment: You never save pointer values in a file. For this case just save name, duration, path

Comment: then how could i load the list in the right order and, i heard about json file format but idk if it suits what i want to do and if possible to give some tips and directions on how to make that

Comment: You can use `fprintf` - see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3p.html

Comment: @Hillskiller The order of data in the file shall be the same as the order in the list. So you kind of get the order "for free"

Comment: like i'm trying to think of a way to save that efficently without much work on loading, i could just save everything path,duraion,name.... but idk how to actually parse the data from the file like which data belongs to which frame...

Comment: Write one line per frame - like `fprintf("%s %d %s\n", name, duration, path);`

Comment: or write them on 3 individual lines

Comment: if their in one line let's say imageOne 200 C:\desktop how could i parse each individual thing by itself like how could i get the values like that?

Comment: Checck `fgets` and `sscanf`

Comment: alright so i made a function that saves output

Comment: it saves them as the following https://pastebin.com/raw/bKrCAS8X
now the question is how do i load them back? @4386427

Comment: As I wrote above. Check `fscanf`  or better: `fgets` and `sscanf`.

Comment: Use a text file, write a frame (3 items) per line. The string shall be written between double quotes (escape double quotes if they are possible in the string) and separate each by a semicolon. A line looks like *"1";200;"C:\Users\magshimim\Desktop\test\tt.png"*. To reload, you'll have to parse each line character by character.

Comment: could you help me in making the function for reloading because ik about looping over each character in loop but not sure how to split ";\n

Comment: [Overlapping questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67777103/parsing-data-from-file-into-linked-list-in-c).